# Database and query to store and retrieve friend list

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I am developing a module in website to save and retrieve friend list. I am using Zend Framework and for DB handling I am using Doctrine(ORM).

There are two models:

1) **users** that stores all the users
2) **my_friends** that stores the friend list  (that is reference table with M:M relation of user)

### the structure of **my_friends** is following

---

...id..........user_id............friend_id........approved....
...10.........20     ..................25...................1..........
...10.........21     ..................25...................1..........
...10.........22     ..................30...................1..........
...10.........25     ..................30...................1..........

---

The Doctrine **query** to retrieve friend list id following

```
$friends = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('my_friends as mf')
                                 ->leftJoin('mf.users as friend')
                                 ->where("mf.user_id = 25")
                                 ->andWhere("mf.approved = 1");
```

Suppose I am viewing the **user no.- 25**.
With this query I am only getting the **user no.- 30**.
where as **user no.- 25** is also approved friend of **user no.- 20 and 21**.
Please guide me, what should be the query to find all friend and is there any need to change the DB structure.

**YAML**
    Member:
    columns:

```
id:
  primary: true
  type: integer
  notnull: true
  autoincrement: true
userName:
  unique: true
  type: string(255)
Address_id:
  type: integer(4)
MemberPhoto_id:
  type: integer
 relations:
address:
  class: Address
  local: Address_id
  foreign: id
memberPhotos:
  class: MemberThumbnail
  foreignAlias: member
  local: MemberPhoto_id
  foreign: id

refPeeps:
columns:
id:
  primary: true
  unique: true
  type: integer
  autoincrement: true
Member_id:
  type: integer
  notnull: true
Peep_id:
  type: integer
  notnull: true
relations:
Member:
  local: Member_id
  foreign: id
Member:
  local: Peep_id
  foreign: id
```

Comment: what is the $id value u passing in the query

Comment: $id value is 25. Sorry for not reffering that

Comment: Im not familiar with doctrine,but have you tried using `where("rp.user_id = 25 && rp.friend_id = 25")` or such method to get from both columns?

Comment: Yup i have tried both && and || but gets nothing :-(.  with && the query only returns where user_id =25 and friend_id = 25

Comment: Apologies for deleting my post.

Comment: @amrKamboj Please don't cross-post the exact same question to multiple SE sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**- Hello Amrit.**

**- I think you need to fetch data with two query. According to me you have to follow these steps**

1. First get  all data with join query corresponding to friend_id.
2. And second time you apply simple query for user_id and get data.
3. And then fetch data corresponding to the second query.

Comment: I think this solution is great. Let me try dat

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how you can express this in Doctrine as I haven't used it in a while, but you need to join my_friends to itself where friend_id = user_id. I could of course be misunderstanding your database layout. If I misunderstood you, please update your question with the PHP schema or the YAML file that generated it.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know doctrine, your query probably it.
if you give example data and example result i can help better

```
SELECT *
FROM my_friend
LEFT JOIN users ON my_friend.friend_id = users.id
WHERE my_friend.user_id = 25
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your table that is the output your should receive

Since you query for the user_id, and with user_id=25 there is only one row

You have two ways to do what you want

1) When you add friend you should create two rows, one is user_id=25 and friend_id=30, second one user_id=30 and friend_id=25

This is a bit ugly but has advantages in building queries

2) Second way does not require any database saves changes, but requires change of query
You should query for:

(user_id=25 or friend_id=25). Not just user_id

Comment: I also think about reverse duplicate entry but when if any user remove any friend then, there needs to remove two entries.This is much ugly trick.....And or condition does not working . It display the same user (ie. user-25), because Friend_id is FK